# how to configure jenkins to run the protractor script (without using gitlab)

Tags: protractor, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to `protractor` and `jenkins`. I am trying to configure `jenkins` to run the `protractor` script, but the out put showing as below:

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\suresh.padmanabhan\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorials\Protractor Tests1
[Protractor Tests1] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins5988193253698839928.bat

C:\Users\suresh.padmanabhan\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorials\Protractor Tests1>protractor C:/Users/suresh.padmanabhan/eclipse-workspace/ProtractorTutorials/Protractor Tests1/conf.js 
'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\suresh.padmanabhan\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorials\Protractor Tests1>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE".
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: Please show the batch cmd you write down in the Jenkins' Build Step: Execute Windows Batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command` hints Protractor is not installed on Jenkins slave machine where your protractor script resides, or Protractor is installed but not expand it to `PATH` environment variable.

Put following batch cmd into your Build Step: Execute Windows Batch, and give a trying.

```
cd "C:\Users\suresh.padmanabhan\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorials\Protractor Tests1"

npm install protractor
.\node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update
.\node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js
```

Comment: Hi Yong, thanks, i tried your suggestion, it is working till webdriver-manager update, but the script is not running. (.\node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js)                                                           + protractor@5.4.2
updated 1 package and audited 914 packages in 3.437s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

Yong was on the right path. The problem is because it is running the commands as if they were in a batch script so you need to write them as if they were. Otherwise it will always exit after the first command as you can see by the output you posted.

Try this instead:

```
cd "C:\Users\suresh.padmanabhan\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorials\Protractor Tests1"

call npm install protractor
call .\node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update
call .\node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install protractor globally and try the next steps.

```
cd "C:\Users\suresh.padmanabhan\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorials\Protractor Tests1"
npm install -g protractor  
.\node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update 
.\node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js
```

Or specify the PATH where protractor has been installed in environment variable